# How to fix error : Error 0xe800007e: The device OS version is too low. ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

i try to run my ionic app

with this line ionic `run ios --device` 
But it stop without error
so i try to run with cordova: cordova run ios --device and i got this error :

`[ !! ] Error 0xe800007e: The device OS version is too low. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
Error: Error code 253 for command: ios-deploy with args: --justlaunch,--no-wifi,-d,-b,/PathToMyAp`

so i set the minimum version required
`<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />`
 but it seems be ignored

can someone help me ?

Comment: Question title does not agree with actual question.

Comment: better like that ?

Answer (score 0):

try to set miniversion 8.0 or 9.0 ，see it can work ？

Comment: i try to set 7.0 , 8.0 is the default value

Comment: you error show that you should set a higher miniversion

Comment: you error show that you should set a higher miniversion

Comment: if set 8.0 you can not install app on iphone4，iphone7 is coming，many company had give up iphone 4 in appstore

Comment: yes it help me but i can't upvote you rigth now i had to have 15 reputation (and i have 14...)

Comment: @JonathanAndreu then mark the answer correct and you'll gain 2 points

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Deployment target in the build settings to the minimum iOS version you require.

A general guideline is to set:

- Base SDK to latest
- deployment target to the minimum version you support.

Also - check your Info.plist file for the `MinimumOSVersion` key.

Regards.

Comment: thanks for your answer i set the deployment version in my config.xml file but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you build project after ?

Comment: Did you tried manually changing min version from project setting in XCode and then build & run ?