# How to solve watch installation error from Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

When attempting to install a WatchKit app to the watch device, through Xcode 8, I'm seeing an error popup that reads "The device OS version is too low."

I already tried setting all deployment targets to values below that of the iPhone OS and the watch. I even tried setting the watchOS Deployment Target, but none of these steps made a difference.

When looking this up, the only link I find has nothing to do with the Watch:
[How to fix error : Error 0xe800007e: The device OS version is too low. ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610290/how-to-fix-error-error-0xe800007e-the-device-os-version-is-too-low-ionic)

Was anyone able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error, "The device OS version is too low," is reported erroneously since the watch app is installed on the device. If it doesn't show immediately, toggling the "Show on Device" button in the watch companion app, to uninstall and reinstall, will enable the app to be installed successfully.